# Change in Area of Event Horizon under Perturbation

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, event-horizon

It is known that if one perturbs Schwarzschild initial data and the perturbation corresponds to a massive particle following an ingoing geodesic which is close to null, then the perturbation can be parametrised in terms of the minimum frequency for the lowest-lying quasi-normal mode $\omega_{\text{min}}$.

It seems that such a perturbation corresponds to a damped oscillation of the inner boundary (ie. the event horizon).  Is it true that this type of perturbation does not change the area of the event horizon, as intuitively the idea seems to be that the perturbation merely causes the inner boundary to oscillate in such a way that the area itself does not change.